# Connecting Pi to an OPC server

Tags: networking, hardware, ethernet

I want to connect a Pi to an OPC-DA server to acquire data over an Ethernet connection. Does the Pi's Ethernet port function for non-internet uses?

Extra twist... if I want to connect to both the OPC and the internet via Ethernet, will it work to make multiple connections using a switch?

Comment: Ethernet is pretty standardized.  It provides exchange of digital data (bytes) between two devices that are relatively local to each other.  Look up OSI model to learn about layered protocols.  Layered protocols are how Ethernet/IP/TCP work to access the internet.<br/>Access to the internet typically means that one of the local Ethernet devices is a Router that will use IP protocol, embedded in an Ethernet message, to forward that message out to the internet.  <br/>Can your OPC-DA server send data over Ethernet?  What protocols does it allow within an Ethernet message?